# Scroll List to a row in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I implemented a list control. I want to scroll the row to center when it is selected. My row contains one image and two texts. Below is my code.

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
        List(videos, id: \.id) { video in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                WebImage(url: URL(string: video.thumbnailURL))
                    .resizable()
                    .placeholder {
                        Rectangle().foregroundColor(.clear)
                    }
                    .transition(.fade(duration: 0.5))
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(minHeight:100.0, alignment: .center)
                Text(video.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .font(Font.custom("Montserrat Bold", size: 14))
                Text(video.artist)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .font(Font.custom("Montserrat Medium", size: 14))
                    .padding(.bottom, 5)
                
            }.background(Color.black)
                .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                .onTapGesture {
                    selectedVideoId = video.id
                    delegate?.videoSelected(video: video)
                }
                .border((selectedVideoId == video.id) ? Color(red: 0.9607843161, green: 0.7058823705, blue: 0.200000003) : Color.clear, width: (selectedVideoId == video.id) ? 1.5 : 0.0)
            
        }.padding(.horizontal, 20.0)
            .padding(.bottom, 10.0)
            .background(Color.clear)
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .onChange(of: selectedVideoId) { vid in
                scrollView.scrollTo(1, anchor: .top)
            }
    }
}
```

The `.onChange(of: selectedVideoId)` closure gets called when a row is selected. But it doesn't scroll to the first row.

Comment: A couple of things: If `Video`, or whatever the type is, is `Identifiable`, you don't need the `id: \.id`. The `List` will automatically use `.id`. If it isn't, make it `Identifiable`. That leads into the `scrollTo`. The`List` is tracking the `ListRow` IDs by `video.id`, not by an index running from 1... If you don't supply the view ID, the `scrollTo` has no idea where to go.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I was trying older way of table view where we needed to pass index of row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ScrollViewReader` works with the `id` of your model items. You should not use the key-path-based initializer `id: \.id`.

Conform your model type to `Identifiable`:

```
struct Video: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let title: String
    let artist: String
    // [...] whatever else you have here
}
```

Use your `Identifiable` model items, assign the `id` to each view & `scrollTo(selectedVideoId)`:

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
                List(v.videos) { video in // << use id here
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        WebImage(url: URL(string: video.thumbnailURL))
                            .resizable()
                            .placeholder {
                                Rectangle().foregroundColor(.clear)
                            }
                            .transition(.fade(duration: 0.5))
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(minHeight:100.0, alignment: .center)
                        Text(video.title)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .font(Font.custom("Montserrat Bold", size: 14))
                        Text(video.artist)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .font(Font.custom("Montserrat Medium", size: 14))
                            .padding(.bottom, 5)
                    }
                    .id(video.id) // << assign the id to each view
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectedVideoId = video.id
                        delegate?.videoSelected(video: video)
                    }
                    .border((selectedVideoId == video.id) ? Color(red: 0.9607843161, green: 0.7058823705, blue: 0.200000003) : Color.clear, width: (selectedVideoId == video.id) ? 1.5 : 0.0)
                    
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 20.0)
                .padding(.bottom, 10.0)
                .background(Color.clear)
                .listStyle(.plain)
                .onChange(of: selectedVideoId) { vid in
                    print("new selected: \(selectedVideoId)")
                    withAnimation {
                        scrollView.scrollTo(selectedVideoId, anchor: .top) 
                        // << scroll to id
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
```

Comment: Got it Thanks. I was trying with mindset of Tableview where we pass row index.

Comment: Do you know how to hide the scroll indicators ?